# SharePoint + InfoPath Data Connections

Tags: sharepoint, infopath

This may be a silly question, but I've been googling it for a bit and I haven't found a good answer yet.  I am designing some forms for a SharePoint site, and the forms use SharePoint lists as an external data source.  I want to pull information into the form (in multiple-selection lists) ONLY if it meets certain criteria (both for speed and because only certain values are valid).  Is this possible?  If not, is there a good workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the answer I came up with seems to work pretty well- I am getting my data from the RESTful API built into SharePoint and filtering the data via my requests.  Hope this helps someone else out there!